# Maximize android app from service

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

I have an application which runs background service which checks notifications which it gets from some server. And when the notification arrives (Ping notification), it opens a new Notification dialog with full screen inflated view. On this screen you have an option to accept the call, which calls another device with SIP voice connection. This accept call opens up a new dialog fragment, which has the ability to automatically answer the call, and the user has the option to cancel it. When I am on main activity window, this works just fine. In service there is view inflated with layout added to window_manager which shows notification and when you accept the call, dialog fragment with call status opens. The question I have now, is it possible to do that while application is minimized?
So for example, user minimized app, service is still running in the background, when the ping notification gets to the device, it shows new notification dialog, but when you want to accept the call and to show fragment, it is not possible because.
1. I don't have current screen on which to show dialog fragment with calling
2. If I create some instance of the current Activity onCreate, and I don't destroy it onDestroy, I can call startActivity on it, but nothing shows up. Call establishes, but I cannot maximize my current activity and show dialog fragment on it.

What can I do in this case? Should I also create some other notification like this one in service and instead of dialog fragment I should be showing another notification?

Comment: What are using for making api calls?

Comment: What do you mean api calls?

Comment: "which it gets from some server" how is this happening?

Comment: This is just some random text send from server, like SERVER??PING every few seconds, but here it gets SERVER??NOTIFICATION.